# jQuery remove class from previous data entry into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Note: this is a jQuery coding exercise and I am not allowed to use plugins or other modules.

I have a simple form validation script. When the user enters in data and it's empty the appropriate error gets displayed.

When the user types in the required field and submits the form again I want the error message to disappear if it's no longer empty and show the appropriate error if other fields are still empty.

I tried the following and the errors still show after entering the required form fields and a resubmission is done.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxjvu95n/)**

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
      <span class="error">Email not entered</span><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pword" name="pword">
      <span class="error">Password not entered</span><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="fname">
      <span class="error">First Name not entered</span><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname">
      <span class="error">Last Name not entered</span><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.error {
    display: none;
}

.error_show {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// jQuery form validation
$(document).ready(function(){

    // remove class from previous data entry
    $('#myform span').removeClass('error_show');

    // field mapping
    var form_fields = {
        'email' : 'email',
        'pword' : 'password',
        'fname' : 'first name',
        'lname' : 'last name'
    };

    // ajax data
    var data = {};

    // make sure form fields were entered
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){

        for (var field in form_fields) {
            if (!$('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field).next().addClass('error_show');
            } else if ($('#' + field).val()) {
                data[field] = $('#' + field).val();
            }
        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to the `else` branch of your validation function:

```
// jquery form validation
$(document).ready(function(){

    // remove class from previous data entry
    $('#myform span').removeClass('error_show');

    // field mapping
    var form_fields = {
        'email' : 'email',
        'pword' : 'password',
        'fname' : 'first name',
        'lname' : 'last name'
    };

    // ajax data
    var data = {};

    // make sure form fields were entered
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){

        for (var field in form_fields) {
            if (!$('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field).next().addClass('error_show');
            } else if ($('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field).next().removeClass('error_show'); // <-- Here .removeClass() is added
                data[field] = $('#' + field).val();
            }
        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

Now the class gets removed when the field has a value.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mxjvu95n/1/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why my ` $('#myform span').removeClass('error_show')` did not do that as I intended?

Comment: it's `$('#myForm span')`, not `$('#myform span')` :) Selectors are case sensitive

Comment: You're calling it only once, the document has loaded (right after `$(document).ready()`. you have to call it every time you check the form. See https://jsfiddle.net/mxjvu95n/7/ line 17

Comment: OK. Thanks! Makes sense now.